# Group by if no records in group is newer than specific data

Tags: sql-server

I'm having a problem with the sql query below.

```
SELECT 
       MAX([DL_Id]) as [DL_Id]
      ,MAX([DL_CreatedBy]) as [DL_CreatedBy]
      ,MAX([DL_Created]) as [DL_Created]
      ,MAX([DL_ModifiedBy]) as [DL_ModifiedBy]
      ,MAX([DL_Modified]) as [DL_Modified]
      ,[DL_StandardLetter]
      ,count(1)
  FROM [DB].[dbo].[DL_StandardLetterStatistics]

  where (DL_Modified < '2018-01-01' or DL_Created < '2018-01-01')
  
  group by DL_StandardLetter

  order by [DL_StandardLetter] asc
```

Right now it's returning all records from `DL_StandardLetterStatistics` where the date is older than 2018 and grouping them by `DL_StandardLetter`.

Having the data below as an example. (there is about 200000 records)

```
| DL_Created | DL_StandardLetter |
 --------------------------------
| 2016-06-06 | 2352              |
| 2019-04-06 | 2352              |
| 2016-06-06 | 2542              |
| 2012-01-01 | 302               |
| 2012-01-01 | 2542              |
| 2017-02-08 | 302               |
```

I only want the result to return `2542 and 302` because all of the results is before 2018. Could anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you want `AND` not `OR`? Sample data and expected results, along with a clear explanation of the requirements will help us help you.

Comment: @Larnu Your point is correct, and it's because I was not creating the question correctly. I can ensure you than modified is always newer than created.

Comment: Which is why we need sample *and* expected results. Although, on a single row, `DL_Created` cannot be greater than `DL_Modified`, clearly in the group it *can* be.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, you have got OR condition in the WHERE clause. So, data is flowing due to the other OR condition. It seems, there are some data quality issues, where DL_Modified is older than DL_Created.

```sql
where (DL_Modified < '2018-01-01' or DL_Created < '2018-01-01')
```

You can have additional HAVING clause, to filter only the records where year < 2018.

```sql
SELECT 
       MAX([DL_Id]) as [DL_Id]
      ,MAX([DL_CreatedBy]) as [DL_CreatedBy]
      ,MAX([DL_Created]) as [DL_Created]
      ,MAX([DL_ModifiedBy]) as [DL_ModifiedBy]
      ,MAX([DL_Modified]) as [DL_Modified]
      ,[DL_StandardLetter]
      ,count(1)
  FROM [DB].[dbo].[DL_StandardLetterStatistics]

  where (DL_Modified < '2018-01-01' or DL_Created < '2018-01-01')
  
  group by DL_StandardLetter
  HAVING YEAR(MAX([DL_CreatedBy])) < 2018
  ORDER BY [DL_StandardLetter] asc
```

Comment: *"It seems, there are some data quality issues, where DL_Modified is older than DL_Created."* Clearly you've not seen/looked at the data for Stack Overflow, where you can have answers that were created several **years** before the question they are linked to. ;)

Comment: Also `HAVING YEAR([DL_CreatedBy]) < 2018` will error due to neither `DL_CreatedBy` or the expression `YEAR([DL_CreatedBy])` being in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Larnu, thanks for the information about the stackoverflow database :-)

Comment: There's also, interestingly, **one** question that was editted *before* it was created: [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1416888)